# Pushing select element value as json

Tags: php, javascript, json

Due to the limitations of the deign of a current system, I need to pass data to a select element as json, reset each option in the select object with the 'id' value from the json and populate a second select element with 'sid' data from the json to create a dynamic parent-child pair of select elements.

However I seem to be unable to successfully parse the option value and push it into an array for use in later code.

```
<select id="Sector">
    <option value="{'id':'Fruit','sid':['Apple','Orange']}"></option>
    <option value="{'id':'Veg','sid':['Tomato','Carrot']}"></option>
</select>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var plist = document.getElementById('Sector');
    var opts = plist.options;
    var x =[];
    for(i=0;i<opts.length;i++){
        x.push(opts[i].value);
    }

    alert(x[0]['id']);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ??i

Answer (score 1):

The option values are **strings**. If you want to treat them as JavaScript objects, you have to run them through [a JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

You will then run into another problem as the option values are **not JSON**. Use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to find your errors (I can't see any aside from you using a `'` every place you should be using a `"`). If you are dealing with JSON, you should almost always be building a data structure in a programming language and then running it through a JSON serializer, handcrafting JSON is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the single quote with double quotes and it passed the test.

Answer (score 1):

this line is an issue

```
   x.push(opts[0]);
```

first off, I think you need to do opts[0].value, then I think you need to use eval or JSON.parse to turn it into an object.

Comment: x.push(JSON.parse(opts[i].value)) fails with "unexpected end of data"

Comment: this works: var opt = opts[i].value.replace(/'/g,'"'); y=JSON.parse(opt); x.push(y);